# Call stored procedure with sequelize

Tags: node.js, stored-procedures, sequelize.js

How do I call a stored procedure with an out parameter?

For example, I have the same stored procedure,

```
create or replace procedure NODEONE(id1 IN NUMBER,name1 OUT varchar2)
AS
begin
select "first_name" into name1 from "users" where "id" = id1;
END NODEONE;
```

Now how can I call it?

I use this:

```
    db.sequelize.query("BEGIN NODEONE(:id1, :name1); END;", {  // bind variables
    id: 1,
    name: { type:sequlize.string},
},
    function (err, result) {
        if (err) { console.error(err.message); return; }
        console.log(result.outBinds);
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

out parameter is SQL server specific, not supported in ORM sequelize.
Instead you can return it via select statement same.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7060) on sequelize GitHub